# Mobile Broadband Not enable (EVDO)

Tags: 11.10, mobile-broadband

I have upgraded my ubuntu with 11.10 i368,after completion of installation i have connected my EVDO card and configured all mobile broadband setting. At first it got connected and was able to surf properly....but after completion of installation and updating all packages (its was like 414 packages to download) i was no more able setup my broadband connection with EVDO.

I always Enable the mobile broadband before conneting,but still i was unable to connect my EVDO.

Any solution????

Answer (score 1):

Has the resolvconf got updated? Go through the following link and give it a shot. Worked for me for my BSNL EVDO (Prithvi dongle)

> You might have issues with resolvconf stomping on your DNS
>   configuration in /etc/resolv.conf - but if you're getting an IP
>   address from the remote peer then the modem is working, even if you
>   can't access any websites etc. If you don't use resolvconf, consider
>   just uninstalling it.

Source: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NetworkManager/Hardware/3G/Probing

Answer (score 0):

Look for comparable reports in Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/?field.searchtext=evdo&search=Search&field.status%3Alist=NEW&field.status%3Alist=OPINION&field.status%3Alist=INVALID&field.status%3Alist=WONTFIX&field.status%3Alist=EXPIRED&field.status%3Alist=CONFIRMED&field.status%3Alist=TRIAGED&field.status%3Alist=INPROGRESS&field.status%3Alist=FIXCOMMITTED&field.status%3Alist=FIXRELEASED&field.status%3Alist=INCOMPLETE_WITH_RESPONSE&field.status%3Alist=INCOMPLETE_WITHOUT_RESPONSE&assignee_option=any&field.assignee=&field.bug_reporter=&field.bug_commenter=&field.subscriber=&field.tag=&field.tags_combinator=ANY&field.status_upstream-empty-marker=1&field.upstream_target=&field.has_cve.used=&field.omit_dupes.used=&field.omit_dupes=on&field.affects_me.used=&field.has_patch.used=&field.has_branches.used=&field.has_branches=on&field.has_no_branches.used=&field.has_no_branches=on&field.has_blueprints.used=&field.has_blueprints=on&field.has_no_blueprints.used=&field.has_no_blueprints=on